# ListStepPlot vs ListLinePlot

Tags: plotting, function-comparison

When I plot the data I have using `ListStepPlot` and `ListLinePlot[data,InterpolationOrder -> 0]` I am getting two different plot. I guess there is a bug in `ListStepPlot`.

```
data={{{0, 1}, {0.0582215, 2}, {0.597255, 3}, {1.17158, 4}}, {{1.17158, 
   4}, {1.36478, 5}, {1.424, 6}, {1.4586, 7}}, {{1.4586, 7}, {1.73938,
    8}, {1.88332, 9}, {2.03753, 10}}, {{2.03753, 10}, {2.17872, 
   11}, {2.46005, 12}, {2.71547, 13}}, {{2.71547, 13}, {3.16095, 
   14}, {3.30726, 15}, {3.5329, 16}}, {{3.5329, 16}, {3.63022, 
   17}, {4.34524, 18}, {5.20954, 19}}};
ListLinePlot[data, Frame -> True, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
 ImageSize -> 600, InterpolationOrder -> 0]
```

[image]

```
ListStepPlot[data, Frame -> True, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
 ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

Here is different data that has a problem

```
data1={{{0, 1}, {0.139219, 2}, {0.607566, 3}, {1.18343, 4}}, {{1.18343, 
   4}, {1.22964, 5}, {2.01722, 6}, {2.62576, 7}}, {{2.62576, 
   7}, {3.69976, 8}, {3.90317, 9}, {4.49939, 10}}, {{4.49939, 
   10}, {4.83385, 11}, {4.92839, 12}, {5.3667, 13}}, {{5.3667, 
   13}, {5.37191, 14}, {5.75267, 15}, {5.86257, 16}}, {{5.86257, 
   16}, {6.49011, 17}, {6.56514, 18}, {6.73022, 19}}};
```

"11.1.0 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit) (March 13, 2017)"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no bug. `ListStepPlot` gives a different result from `ListLinePlot` because it is using a different plotting algorithm.

`ListStepPlot` draws steps (horizontal lines) through the data points and gives the user a choice of three positions for where the data point stands on the horizontal line. It will always extend the first or last step as required to get a full step at that point.

`ListLinePlot` with `InterpolationOrder -> 0` joins the data points with staircase polyline, which is quite a different thing.

To visualize the differences of the plotting methods, we need only give the option `Mesh -> Full` which makes the data points visible.

```
ListStepPlot[data, Right,
  Frame -> True, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", Mesh -> Full]
```

[image: right]

`Right` is the default value for mesh point position.

```
ListStepPlot[data, Center,
 Frame -> True, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", Mesh -> Full]
```

[image: center]

```
ListStepPlot[data, Left,
  Frame -> True, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", Mesh -> Full]
```

[image: left]

```
ListLinePlot[data,
  Frame -> True, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", InterpolationOrder -> 0, Mesh -> Full]
```

[image: line]

It is up to you to chose the one which displays your data more clearly.

Comment: Thanks for clarification but at least one option of `ListLinePlot` should produce the same plot as `ListLinePlot`. I will go with `ListLinePlot` since that's what I want.

Answer (score 3):

`ListStepPlot` always produces a step shape. You can decide where you want the resulting "extra bit" of the curve with a second argument.

```
data = {{{1, 2}, {2, 3}}, {{3, 4}, {4, 5}}};
left = ListStepPlot[data, Left, Mesh -> Full, Frame -> True, 
   PlotTheme -> "Detailed", ImageSize -> 600];
center = ListStepPlot[data, Center, Mesh -> Full, Frame -> True, 
   PlotTheme -> "Detailed", ImageSize -> 600];
right = ListStepPlot[data, Right, Mesh -> Full, Frame -> True, 
   PlotTheme -> "Detailed", ImageSize -> 600];
Row[{left, center, right}]
```

[image]